# How to take Instagram like square size picture

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have a question of how to take a square size picture like Instagram. There might be posts like this but I haven't find any particularly helpful to me. Here's my problem: I tried to call getSupportedPictureSize() and see most of supported picture size are rectangular, while those few square size pictures are in low resolution. On the other hand if I set the preview size to square with rectangular picture then the preview looked stretched. Anyone has any idea of how I can do that? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot take a picture of size not supported by camera. But you can crop the image you receive in your picture callback.

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there a way to crop the preview before picture callback (take picture action)?

Comment: I guess you want to show preview (viewfinder) that will reflect the capture result, when (and if) shutter button is pressed. You can control the preview in different ways. Probably the easiest is to use the standard SurfaceView that you assign as the holder of the Camera preview, but overlay this view with non-transparent panels of desired geometry.

Comment: Thanks again Alex! Now I think I know what to do!

Comment: Kindly check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176270/android-camera-preview-on-a-square-screen-stretched/35054199#35054199