# Android Camera Preview on a square screen stretched

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm building an app for Android but The device do have a square screen. The screen is 320x320 and the camera app use the SurfaceView to show the preview as below :

```
    mCameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    LayoutParams params = mCameraView.getLayoutParams();
    int camera_dimension = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.camera_dimension);
    params.height = camera_dimension; //320px
    params.width = camera_dimension;

    mCameraView.setLayoutParams(params);
    mCameraViewHolder = mCameraView.getHolder();
    mCameraViewHolder.addCallback(this);
    mCameraViewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

On Surface changed, I'm doing this and it works but the supporter preview is w480 x h320

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    int mWidth = w;
    int mHeight = h;
    int mFormat = format;

    try {
        mCameraAccess.mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    Camera.Parameters param = mCameraAccess.mCamera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> SupportedPreview = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int ScreenSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.camera_dimension);

    for (int i = 0; i < SupportedPreview.size(); i++) {
        if (SupportedPreview.get(i).height == ScreenSize) {
            param.setPreviewSize(SupportedPreview.get(i).width, SupportedPreview.get(i).height);
            break;
        }
    }
    mCameraAccess.mCamera.setParameters(param);
    mCameraAccess.mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

How can make sure that my preview inside the viewholder is not compressed but a kind of centercrop. As the preview is a rectangle, I just need the square centered on the image. Usually I'm using scaleType but it's not supported in Surface view

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

The solution which i have figured out is:

> 1)-Keep surface view full screen,so that is doesn't stretch.
>
> 2)-Put a view over surfaceview with full opacity.So that is looks like camera  is already squared.
>
> 3)-After capturing image or video,you will have to crop them.
>
> For video you have to use some video processing library like javacv.Using this library you can extract video frames,convert them to bitmap,crop bitmap in square and then re-encode into video.
>
> To get accurate results you will need to play around with different techniques like zooming camera during capture etc. according to your needs.

Original Image:

[image]

Squared Image:

[image]